# I get no audio on my new Quansheng uv-5r plus despite green receive light

Tags: uv-5r, audio

Quansheng uv-5r plus. First time on these devices, sorry.
The receive light goes on but no receive audio.
Transmit on ht works fine. Audio from device prompts are ok.
Checked frequency traffic with another ht and found no issues. Is there a squelch control on this device?

Answer (score 1):

I think CTCSS/DCS is the cause of my problem.The ht has a monitor key which when pressed turned on the audio. By default, however, it turned off when another frequency is selected. I think the reason why there is no audio for incoming transmissions is because the CTCSS/DCS on the ht is set differently. Assuming that is correct I now need to figure out how to correct that issue.

Comment: Well spotted. It may have an "open" setting, like CTCSS Off. It may also be able to scan for the tone, if the transmitter stays on for a while. If you're searching, in general I find people favour the lower tones because above 100 Hz they start to be audible.